# Parse.com and React Native: Add Fields for Current User

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, react-native

I am working on a React Native application using a parse.com backend. I have the user registration figured out, in which the user logs-in/signs-up with a username and password. This info is stored in the parse user object. I am having trouble on the following screen where the user enters additional information: first name, last name, and phone number. I have set up corresponding fields in the parse user object: "firstName", "lastName", and "phone".

Here is the code I have to set these fields:

```
enterInfo: function() {
var self = this;
var firstName = this.state.firstName;
var lastName = this.state.lastName;
var phone = this.state.phone;
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();

 if (firstName.length && lastName.length && phone.length) {
  if (currentUser) {
    currentUser.set("firstName", firstName);
    currentUser.set("lastName", lastName);
    currentUser.set("phone", phone);

    self.setState({
        error: null
      }); 
  } else {
      self.setState({
        error: 'Fill in all required fields'
      });
    }
}
}
```

I think the problem may be with the way I am determining the current user, however, I am not sure how to do it correctly.

Comment: Have you tried logging out the currentUser variable after assigning it to Parse.User.current() ? Also, are you receiving error messages, or is it that you are not getting the functionality you expect? Thanks.

Comment: I'm just not seeing the info entered into the fields on parse.

Comment: I tried logging out the currentUser variable and it did not work so it seems I am not assigning the current user to the variable correctly.